# Load Smartcontract in Nodejs

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nodejs, npm

I created the server based on golang.
This server can load smart contract that is deployed using its address.
It works on my local machine, but it does not work on EC2 instance.
So I decided to develop it based on nodejs.
But I can't find how it can load same smart contract in nodejs.
Please help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the contract object via:

```
const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface), smartContractAddress);
```

Comment: thanks for replying.
I wonder what the interface is.
is It json data based on abi file?

Comment: yes it is the contract ABI